# Create service principal using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

It seems that the **Azure AD Graph API** made it possible to create a *service principal* via the REST API endpoint shown below. I am looking for the same functionality in the Microsoft Graph API, yet it doesn't seem to exist in v1.0 or beta.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this through the Microsoft Graph API?

**From Azure AD Graph API:**

**POST:**

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6
```

**Authorization: Bearer {access_token}**

```
{
  "appId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "accountEnabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the Service principal using MS Graph. Please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

POST :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals
Content-type: application/json

{
  "appId": "65415bb1-9267-4313-bbf5-ae259732ee12",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be now done using the Microsoft Graph module (via nuget package).

```
IGraphServiceClient  graphClient;    
graphClient.ServicePrincipals.Request().AddAsync(serviceprincipal);
```

[Microsoft Doc - Create Service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)